# Looking for a complete(ish) u-boot shell syntax guide

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, u-boot

I am looking for a complete(ish) u-boot shell syntax guide. Supposedly it is the Hush Shell, but I cannot find good guides for this shell either.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, but I think finding a syntax guide, if one exists, is a much better solution, and would be beneficial to more people than numerous one off questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about U-boot, but Hush is based on the Tcl environment, and its user guide probably assumes some familiarity with that.

There's an [old copy of its manual](https://web.archive.org/web/19970719184958/www.cs.vu.nl/~hush/manuals) on the web archive, dating back to 1997!
There's a [FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/hush-faq/), which might be more up-to-date.

Comment: Yea I have yet to find anything that would qualify as a solid reference. Not sure what is going on, insider only knowledge perhaps. I have a few Linux books that barely skim the topic.